# How to list all pending friend requests for a given user ID?

Tags: mysql

I have a friendship table like this

[image]

A and B are friends if there are (A,B) and (B,A) rows. For example, uid 132 & 67 are friends indicated by (132,67) on 2nd row and (67,132) on ninth row. Rows 4 - 8 are pending requests to uid 132.

My question is how to list all pending requests to uid X? I tried this (X=132):

```
SELECT a.uid1, a.uid2 FROM tbl_friendship a LEFT JOIN tbl_friendship b ON a.uid1=b.uid2 AND a.uid2=b.uid2 WHERE a.uid1 IS NULL AND b.uid2 =132
```

Still not right because the result is empty. The expected result is something like:

```
83, 90, 93, 94, 97
```

How to fix the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to list all pending requests to uid X? I tried this (X=132)

```
SELECT GREATEST(uid1, uid2), LEAST(uid1, uid2)
FROM tbl_friendship 
WHERE 132 IN (uid1, uid2)
GROUP BY 1, 2
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

> I'm only interested to find everyone who send friend request to 132. – anta40

```
SELECT t1.uid2
FROM tbl_friendship t1
WHERE t1.uid2 = 132
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM tbl_friendship t2
                   WHERE (t1.uid1, t1.uid2) = (t2.uid2, t2.uid1) );
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the `GROUP BY`, these are the aliases of `GREATEST`, `LEAST`?

Comment: @danblack *Columns selected for output can be referred to in ORDER BY and GROUP BY clauses using column names, column aliases, **or column positions**. Column positions are integers and begin with 1.* [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  SELECT Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html).

Answer (score 0):

With a self join on `friendship` and having one table as the `friendship_request` and the other as the `existing`. So search the `friend_requests` where there is no `existing_friend` (the `IS NULL` criteria).

```
SELECT friend_request.uid1 as requested_friendship
FROM friendship as friend_request
LEFT JOIN friendship as existing_friend
       ON friend_request.uid1 = existing_friend.uid2
          AND existing_friend.uid1 = X
WHERE friend_request.uid2=X
   AND existing_friend.uid1 IS NULL
```

Note: this assumes the friendship relationship is unidirectional

Comment: Hmm so what are the structures of the `friendship_request` and `friendship` tables?

Comment: `friendship_request` is an alias (the `FROM ` clause) of the `friendship` table you put in the question.